# Error: Incorrect syntax near '@variable' in stored procedure in azure sql database

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a stored procedure with parameters in an Azure SQL Database - Basic Managed Instance, through the Query Editor.

Any time I make reference to any parameter, I get a syntax error, independently of the rest of the SQL code.

I have been successful creating stored procedures without parameters.

Even the simplest code leads to an error:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure
   @masterPassword varchar(50)
AS      
BEGIN

    OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = @masterPassword;

END
```

I would not expect any errors. However, I still receive this error:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: Incorrect syntax near '@masterPassword'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE testProcedure
   @masterPassword varchar(50)
AS      
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SELECT NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @SELECT=N'OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @masterPassword + ''' '; --Expecting String

    EXEC (@SELECT);

END
```

--UNIT TESTING-

```
--error
 select ''' + @in + '''

--corrected method
declare @a nvarchar(50),@in varchar(50);
set @in=cast('hi' as varchar(50));
select @a=' select ''' + @in + ''' ';
exec (@a)
```

Comment: Thanks, but, although the stored procedure is now being created without errors, the string is being interpreted as `'@masterPassword'`, not as the actual parameter. Is this something you'd expect @Arulmouzhi?

Comment: exactly so! I figured out the need for using `EXEC` a few hours before your update, but thank you for anyway.